# change the dtype of a numpy structured array in place without changing other dtypes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an input structured array with unknown number of columns and rows. Among those fields, some are timestamps. However, those timestamps are all np.datetime64[ns] data type. I would like to change them all into np.datetime64[m] data type without changing other columns.

I have tried

```
array["time"] = array["time"].astype("datetime64[m]")
```

but it will not change the original structured array. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Simplest is to define a new compound dtype with the change in the 'time' field, and copy over data field by field. It might be possible to make a view with the new dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Define two dtypes:

```
In [220]: dt1 = [('x','int'),('time','datetime64[ns]')]
In [221]: dt2 = [('x','int'),('time','datetime64[m]')]
```

an array with the first:

```
In [222]: arr = np.array([(1, '2022-01-23T00:34:59.1233'),(2, '2022-01-23T03:00:01.234')],dt1)
In [223]: arr
Out[223]: 
array([(1, '2022-01-23T00:34:59.123300000'),
       (2, '2022-01-23T03:00:01.234000000')],
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('time', '<M8[ns]')])
```

Looks like `astype` properly converts the times:

```
In [224]: arr.astype(dt2)
Out[224]: 
array([(1, '2022-01-23T00:34'), (2, '2022-01-23T03:00')],
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('time', '<M8[m]')])
```

Or as I commented:

```
In [225]: res = np.zeros(2, dt2)
In [226]: res
Out[226]: 
array([(0, '1970-01-01T00:00'), (0, '1970-01-01T00:00')],
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('time', '<M8[m]')])
In [227]: for field in arr.dtype.names: res[field]= arr[field]
In [228]: res
Out[228]: 
array([(1, '2022-01-23T00:34'), (2, '2022-01-23T03:00')],
      dtype=[('x', '<i8'), ('time', '<M8[m]')])
```

The `recfunctions` usually do something along this line - define a new dtype, and copy fields as needed.

Comment: problem solved. Thanks a lot.